# unable to pass Spring Security authentication

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Unable to pass spring security authentication

> AuditEvent [timestamp=2018-07-05T12:08:06.306Z,
>   principal=anonymousUser, type=AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE,
>   data={details=org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@0:
>   RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId:
>   EF4FF849385896FA97E6E071393AC5E7,
>   type=org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException,
>   message=Access is denied}]

My configuration:

```
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@Configuration
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter{

    //@Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        security.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
            .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()")
            .allowFormAuthenticationForClients();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
            .withClient("clientId")
            .secret("secret")
            .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code")
            .scopes("user_info")
            .autoApprove(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean);
    }
}

@EnableResourceServer
@Configuration
public class ResourceServerConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    //@Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean;

    @Bean(name = BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.requestMatchers()
            .antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize")
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.parentAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean)
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("sumit")
            .password("sumit")
            .roles("USER");
    }
}

application.properties
server.port=8081
server.servlet.context-path=/auth


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rest/hello")
public class HelloResource {

    @GetMapping("/principal")
    public Principal user(Principal principal) {
        return principal;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public String hello() {
        return "hello world";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
.antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize")
```

to:

```
.antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize").permitAll()
```

You are probably getting caught on trying to authorize.